# How to get and send Json strings in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have simulator as you can see in the pictures. In this simulator I have a send button that will trigger sending a JSON string appended to a URL.

I test this with the URL *localhost/ussd/index.php*

#### The index.php page:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input= json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE );

$data["message"]='We  Display This in Phone Screen';
$data["applicationId"]=$input["applicationId"];
$data["password"]="password";
$data["version"]="1.0";
$data["sessionId"]=$input["sessionId"];
$data["ussdOperation"]="mt-cont";
$data["destinationAddress"]=$input["sourceAddress"];
$data["encoding"]="440";
$data["chargingAmount"]="5";

$json_string = json_encode($data);
$json_url = "http://localhost:7000/ussd/send";
 
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

$result =  curl_exec($ch); 

?>
```

Then index.php file gets this string and sends another string to that page. The simulator page gets this JSON object and displays it. This can be done in the *index.php* file.

But I want to do it in Laravel. I tried But not Work How can I do it.

It works like this:
[image: It works like that => image]

Comment: I tried like that

Comment: How is laravel related to this question?

Comment: `request()->json()->all()` is the way to extract json from request

Comment: It will benefit yourself and the community if you take a second to show what you have done, what is working and what isn't working. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you everyone I found Answer**

**web.php like that**

Route::post('test3', 'UssdController@test3');

**UssdController.php like that**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
class UssdController extends Controller
{
    public function test3(Request $request){

       $data=array(
           "message" =>'We  Display This in Phone Screen',
           "applicationId"=>$request->applicationId,
               "password"=>"password",
            "version"=>"1.0",
            "sessionId"=>$request->sessionId,
            "ussdOperation"=>"mt-cont",
           "destinationAddress"=>$request->sourceAddress,
            "encoding"=>"440",
            "chargingAmount"=>"5",
       );

        $jsonData =json_encode($data);// response()->json($data);
        $json_url = "http://localhost:7000/ussd/send";

        $ch = curl_init( $json_url );
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonData
        );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $result =  curl_exec($ch);
        Log::info($result);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scenario as i understood from your image and your codes is:

1. You have a form.
2. You filled the form and gave the post request to `localhost/ussd/index.php`.
3. Your code filters the data and sends the request to`http://localhost:7000/ussd/send` with additional data.
4. The simulator gets the data and displays.

For this scenario you first need to have a form and i am creating forms adding `Laravel Collective` to use the `{!! !!}`.

You also can use it by following this docs:

> https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

**form.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'ussd.store']) !!}
    {!! Form::input('applicationId') !!}
    {!! Form::password('password') !!}
    {!! Form::input('sessionId') !!}
    {!! Form::input('sourceAddress') !!}
{!! Form::Close() !!}
```

You also need to create the route for this action as:

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('ussd', 'UssdController');
```

I am using `store` method but since you are not storing the data you could send request to any post method.

**UssdController.php**

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class UssdController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [];
        $data["message"]='We  Display This in Phone Screen';
        $data["applicationId"]=$request["applicationId"];
        $data["password"]=$request["password"];
        $data["version"]="1.0";
        $data["sessionId"]=$request["sessionId"];
        $data["ussdOperation"]="mt-cont";
        $data["destinationAddress"]=$request["sourceAddress"];
        $data["encoding"]="440";
        $data["chargingAmount"]="5";

        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://localhost:7000/']);
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'ussd/send', $data);
        return $response->getBody();
    }
}
```

I suppose the `http://localhost:7000` is your different application where i am sending the `POST` data.

You can use GuzzleHttp to send the request to the different application.
To install `guzzlehttp` use:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

I don't know what you will do after send the data to the simulator, but it should work with some tweaks.

To know more about guzzleHttp you could follow this docs:

> http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thank You for your answer, But It show some error

**ServerException in RequestException.php line 111:
Server error: `POST http://localhost:7000/ussd/send` resulted in a `500 Server Error` response:**

Comment: @LilanthaRajapaksha could you explain me more about your `localhost:7000` server. How does it works? or have you checked is `ussd/send` url is working? `500 Server Error ` means there is something issue with your server i.e. your requesting server. Also check if your url accepts `POST` request.

Comment: I can sent small demo video, Its okkk

Comment: @LilanthaRajapaksha Sure will help you. But i might not help more if there is some issue with your server you are requesting.

Comment: Sorry, Could you add your video in some place from where i could have a look at your issue.

Comment: follow this link u can undestand **[Follow this link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxaDlM38YTc7VzhPODZzS2VpbVk?usp=sharing)**

Comment: @LilanthaRajapaksha could you send me the information on what resides inside `http://localhost:7000/ussd/send` url? I hope there might be something on your url

Comment: I do not know about this URL but if I use following php file (index.php).It is work. but I try the same code **Laravel** . It is not work. I want to know how build this project in **Laravel**